# update cell value if value not already in

Tags: php, mysql

I have to update the column `File` on the TABLE `TEST`. This column contains the files related to the row. Each file is separated by a `|`.

An example could be

```
ID    NAME    FILE
 1    apple   fruit.png | lemon.png
```

Now when I add a new file to the `FILE` column I use this query:

```
$link->query("UPDATE TEST SET File = CONCAT(File, '$dbfilename') WHERE id = '$p_id'")
```

where `$dbfilename` can be e.g. `pineapple.jpg |`

The problem is that, if `$dbfilename` is already on the `File` values, it will be added another time, resulting double.

How can I check if `File` contains already `$dbfilename`, and if yes, don't add id, or even don't execute the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good way of storing information in a database.  But I'll get to that in a second.  To directly answer your question, you *could* use this as your SQL query:

```
UPDATE TEST SET File = CONCAT(File, '$dbfilename')
WHERE id='$p_id'
    AND File NOT LIKE '%$dbfilename%'
    AND Lingua='$linguadilavoro'
```

However, this may cause some issues when one file `pineapple.jpg` and you try to add `another-pineapple.jpg`

Really, I think you should consider how this is a horribly bad approach to databases.  Consider breaking the files off into a second table.  For example:

```
# a table for the fruit names
CREATE TABLE fruits (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX(name)
);

# a table for file names
CREATE TABLE files (
    fileid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fruitid INT UNSIGNED,
    filename VARCHAR(250),
    UNIQUE INDEX(fruitid, filename)
);

# find all of the fruits with their associated files
SELECT fruits.id, fruits.name, files.filename
FROM fruits LEFT JOIN files ON fruits.id=files.fruitid

# add a file to a fruit
INSERT INTO files (fruitid, filename)
VALUES ('$fruitID', '$filename')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fruitid=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

Comment: All clear. Thanks, I'll use this method... In fact separate files in a cell with | is stupid... Cells are the already the smallest entity, so use dividers inside cells is non sense...

Comment: If a file is related to more than one fruit, with the `UNIQUE INDEX(filename)` this solution isn't working anymore. How can I fix that?

Comment: Look at my answer again - don't do `UNIQUE INDEX(filename)`, do `UNIQUE INDEX(fruitid, filename)` - in other words, do the index based on both the fruitid and the filename (so the file exists only once per fruit id).

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` this shouldn't be: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fileid =LAST_INSERT_ID(fileid )` ?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to select out the `FILE` for the id.

then use explode to break it into an array

then  check use in_array to determine if it should be added or not

Here is some (untested) code for guidance

```
$stmt = $link->query("SELECT File File from TEST WHERE id = '$p_id'");
$rec = $stmt->fetchAssoc();
$files = explode(" | ",$rec["FILE"]);
if (!in_array($dbfilename, $files)){
    // add to FILE
} else {
    // it's already there
}
```

Comment: it should be noted this could cause a problem if two web-requests are made at the same time; they would both perform the `SELECT`, not see their file, and then either add duplicate entries or possibly overwrite one another's changes depending on how the `UPDATE` command is used.

Comment: Thank you, this is also a solution, but I think I'll prefer the one proposed by cegfault!

Comment: In other words, this is a good solution, but only in the case that we can be reasonably assured that no item will be updated twice in a short amount of time

Comment: it would only be safe within a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I would redesign your table structure and add a new table File with the following columns instead of using a varchar field for multiple values:

```
Table Test
TableId, Name

Table File
FileId, TestId, FileName
```